# Django, pagination over multiple queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to provide an api endpoint where it gives a paginated response over multiple queryset.

```
a = Foo.objects.filter_a()
b = Foo.objects.filter_b()


paginator = Paginator(a + b, 10) # a + b is just symbolic, add two querysets

page = 3
qs = paginator.page(page)
```

suppose each page has 10 elements, # of `a` is 23 then page-3 would return 3 from `a` and 7 from `b`

And we have to assume that `a` and `b` could be potentially large, and it's ideal to keep the queryset's lazyness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`union`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) to combine two or more querysets:

```
paginator = Paginator(a.union(b, all=True), 10)
```

[OR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#or) operator `|` could work also:

```
paginator = Paginator(a | b, 10)
```

Comment: wow it's that easy.. I just confirmed it is lazy by using `from django.db import connection
    connection.queries`

I know it was not possible with old django..